# Adding Firestore items to localstorage Favourites list - Ionic / Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Ionic / Angular app, reading a list of entries from a Firestore DB.

The list and master / detail functionality was built using the tutorial from here:

https://javebratt.com/crud-ionic-firestore/

I want to add a 'Favourite' button on the item detail page. The functionality should save that item to locastorage (I'm guessing) as every user of the app would have a different Favourites list.

The app will also have a Favourites tab to retrieve and list all the favourites on the page. Like the full listing page from the DB, but obviously just the ones flagged as favourite.

How would I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could create an array favorites[], and add a click listener to the 'favoriteButton' that adds the object with it's variables to the array. You should also make the function linked to the click listener check whether the object is already added to the favorites array or not. Users should also have their own personal favorites array, so whenever a user logs out and returns to your website, their favorites list should still be available, this could be done with linked ID's.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. It is an Ionic app, and there is no user login. So any functionality would have to be written to the device local storage...